# Graph Regression - Is that possible?

Tags: regression, data-visualization, graph-theory

**DATA**

- 30 individuals;
- Each individual has an associated graph;
- Individuals graphs represent the connections between brain regions: nodes are brain regions, while edges' weights are the strengths of the connections. There are 100 brain regions, which are the same across subjects. It implies a total of 4950 edges;
- Each individual has an associated scale (accuracy during a task). So they can be ordered from the worst to the best in that scale.

**AIM**

I want to build a model starting from individual graphs. The model should generate the graph expected, given an accuracy score. So, it sounds like a "graph regression".

I am aware that this is not simple, so not only straight answers but also suggestions on how to approach the problem are appreciated.

Comment: That doesn't like something that can be solved with 30 data points. You're trying to infer a particular graph structure out of 2^{n choose 2} possible graphs given 30 examples? And you want to do this based on one variable (accuracy score?).

Comment: I agree with the comment above. You could perhaps regress accuracy against a simpler summary statistic like number of edges.

Comment: I thank both of you for your comments.
I can use more subjects (up to a maximum of 250) but still the question is the same. Additionally, if you think that this can or cannot be solved in some way, you should justify your answer.

Answer (score 1):

A simple approach could be to cast the unit of observation as the edge, and the node as a covariate to be treated as a grouping factor.  Your outcome would be the accuracy score.  The model would thus be

$$
\text{accuracy score}_{ij} = f(X_i, X_j)
$$

where $i$ indexes outgoing node, $j$ the incoming node, and $X$ characteristics of that node.  Perhaps you have other covariates, but at minimum you can calculate various sorts of centrality measures.  The $f$ could be most anything, from a mixed effects regression to a random forest.

Or, if you want to predict linkage based on an accuracy score, you could fit a model like

$$
pr(\text{linkage})_{ij} = f(X_i, X_j)
$$

with accuracy scores among the $X$'s.  Fitted values of this model would create a probabilistic graph.

More detailed suggestions are probably possible with more info on your data.

Comment: This is an useful answer. Thanks.
There is the possibility to include further covariates (i.e. more psychological measures), and in my opinion a mixed effects model is quite appropriate anyway, even if I was initially thinking at multivariate regression.